# Run mplayer using subprocess in Python erro

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, mplayer

I want to run mplayer using python and here is my code

```
from subprocess import call 
call (mplayer /root/Desktop/file.mp4)
```

but it is not working I got this error

```
File "two.py", line 8, in <module>
    call ("mplayer /root/Desktop/file.mp4")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a list of args with *shell=False*(which is the default):

```
call(["mplayer", "/root/Desktop/file.mp4"])
```

Or with a single  string you would need *shell=True*:

```
call("mplayer /root/Desktop/file.mp4", shell=True)
```

But there is no need for the latter, the first will work fine.